# Regex to replace All Georgian symbols to regular latin symbols

Tags: java, string

I want to replace  all  georgian  symbols in a  string  with  latin symbols  for  example  , if i have  georgian text "ლეჩხუმი" after  conversion i should  have word  like this "lechkhumi" how  should i make  this  task:

1. should  i make map  in  which  i have georgian symbols   with corresponding lating  symbols  for example converSionMap.put("ჩ","ch")?
2. should  i  use  unicode?
3. is   there any  simple  way  to  make this  task?

Comment: you basically want an translator?

Comment: no  i want to   replace  georgian symbols  with  english without  any  particular  sense

Comment: can you share the a list of gregorian symbols?

Comment: Then you should go with a map where you match the symbols to latin. Then you iterate all characters of the string, fetch the "translated" char and replace them

Comment: here  is  georgian  alphabet:https://www.google.ge/search?q=georgian+symbols++alphabet&rlz=1C1GCEA_enGE770GE771&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh-q3Rqb7aAhUHyqYKHQJaAD8QsAQIPA&biw=1440&bih=794#imgrc=OGRuRaBJkztkUM:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example code using a `map` to repalce every character:

```
Map<Character, Character> charMap = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
charMap.put('ლ', 'A');
charMap.put('ე', 'B');
charMap.put('ჩ', 'C');
charMap.put('ხ', 'D');
charMap.put('უ', 'E');
charMap.put('მ', 'F');
charMap.put('ი', 'G');
String s = "ლეჩხუმი";

for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if (charMap.get(c) != null)
        s = s.replace(c, charMap.get(c));
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Requires you to adjust the map as you want it. Current output is: `ABCDEFG`

Comment: that will throw exception for anything that doesn't contain the value